# Heroku Django, templatedoesnotexist error

Tags: django, templates, heroku

So after couple late night works, I finally had my app deployed onto the Heroku, but now a different issue, and sleepless night, the template does not exist

error,
I'm using Django.1.11, so my setting is as following;

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'photos',
]
```

and my TEMPLATES is as following, as from the doc, the installed app, with APP_DIR set to be true, would look for the templates folder within the apps.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And finally my app structure;

|mysite
|photos
----|templates
--------|photos
------------|index.html

when I load the page, I can see from the log;

```
Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/photos/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/photos/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /app/photos/templates/photos/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

The last line, shows the correct path, but somehow, it cannot be found, I really dont know why, can someone shed some lights !

Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: the last one is not showing the correct path, it shows `/app/photos/templates/photos/index.html` but the path for that template is: `/app/photos/templates/photos/templates/index.html`

Comment: @Nazkter the /app should point to the photos ? there's a typo in my structure, the last templates folder shoulnt be there, so the path should be correct, surperisly, I can open the login and registration html under the same folder, but just not index.html

Comment: I think I find the answer myself, somehow, the index.html is reserved? after i change the page to be main.html, everything seems to be working. rather strange.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add explicitly the path for the template folder, you can set it like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'photos/templates/photos/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```