# Django website in heroku missing template in just one specific page

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I had deployed a website in Heroku. Everything was just fine. But today, I just added one new page, added few requirements and deployed it again but it shows template does not exist error for that new page. Everything else is just fine and running smoothly. Only with that one single page, it's showing the error. The page runs fine on the localhost too.

This is the error:[image]

How can this happen ? And what's the solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Firstyle check your "TEMPLATES"  in settings.py. Also, can you look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070625/heroku-django-templatedoesnotexist-error

Comment: I haven't touched the templates section in settings because everything was running just fine. I did check that question but didn't help. I think templates path is ok since all other pages are running and all of them are on the same directory.

Comment: Does it work on your local machine? What's the relevant `urls.py` entry?

Comment: In your image, the Template-loader postmortem tells you where it is looking for the template.  There are 4 locations, each with Source does not exist.  Do you expect the template to be at 1 of those, or at some place it is not looking?  And did you restart the web server?

Comment: Didn't find the error but deleted and created a new heroku app. Deployed everything again and migrated. That solved it. Thanks guys.